# Change color of one row in table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexigrid

I have table and JQuery dialog for manipulating data.
I want to change backgroun color of manipulated row when I press save on dialog to highlight row that i changed or added. 
How is it possible?
I use flexigrid for generating table.
Thx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
$("tr","table#<id>").get(<row Index>).css"background-color", <colour>);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define two CSS classes for your table: a class for normal row, and the other for the selected row.

You can then delete btw. add (change) the classes for a row with `addClass/romoveClass`.